# print markers with v2 API with different order than the table info

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps-api-2, markers

i have a sql query and i pass the result with mysql_fetch_array into a while loop, and i am printing a table. The think is that with the same info included in each row i am building the markers on the map.
As i am building the map, the problem is that the map always centered at the final row of the table (C marker). Instead of this i want the map centered to the marker A (first row of the table).
I was searching about to reverse the array but doesn't work.

```
  <?php
   while($info4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
   {    

   ?>   


      // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
      function createMarker(point, name, html, flag) 
      {
        //set the icon of the marker        
        var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
        letteredIcon.image = "markers/"+flag+".png";

         // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
        markerOptions = { icon:letteredIcon };
        var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        // add a line to the side_bar html
        side_bar_html += '<td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><\/td>';
         return marker;
      }


      // add the points   
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php print $info4['placeY'];?>,<?php print $info4['placeX'];?>), 14);    
      var point = new GLatLng(<?php print $info4['placeY'];?>,<?php print $info4['placeX'];?>);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php print utf8_decode($info4['placeName']);?>","<?php print utf8_decode($info4['placeName'])."<br>".utf8_decode($info4['placeAddress'])."<br>".utf8_decode($info4['placeDistrict']);?>","<?=$flag;?>")
      map.addOverlay(marker);

    <?php  $flag=$flag+1;
    } ?>
```

An example:
Table:

A   Sight-seeing    Odeon

B   Sight-seeing    Phenomenon of Tides

C   Sight-seeing    Red House

In this example the map is centered on the C marker instead of A marker which i want to see.

Comment: Are you are aware that the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010? The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013. New development in this API is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of using while loop, the correct code is below.

```
    //make an array
    $rows = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
//push the rows to the empty array
    array_push($rows, $row);
}
// reverse the order of the rows
$reversedarray=array_reverse($rows);
    //use the info of each row as the variable $info4 
foreach ($reversedarray as $info4) {
    //the code
```